# How to count rows based on multiple column conditions using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I count csv file rows with pandas using `&` and `or` condition?

In the below code I want to count all rows that have True/False=FALSE and status = OK, and have '+' value in any of those columns openingSoon, underConstruction, comingSoon.

I've tried:

```
checkOne =  df['id'].loc[(df['True/False'] == 'FALSE') & (df['status'] == 'OK') & (df['comingSoon'] == '+') or (df['openingSoon'] == '+') or (df['underConstruction'] == '+')].count()
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1329, in __nonzero__
raise ValueError(
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `|` for bitwise `or` and for count `True`s values filtering not necessary, use `sum`:

Also for testing boolean `df['True/False'] == False` is possible simplify by `~df['True/False']`

```
checkOne =  (~df['True/False'] & 
             (df['status'] == 'OK') & 
             (df['comingSoon'] == '+') | 
             (df['openingSoon'] == '+') | 
             (df['underConstruction'] == '+')).sum()
```

If `True/False` are strings `TRUE/FALSE` use:

```
checkOne =  ((df['True/False'] == 'FALSE') & 
             (df['status'] == 'OK') & 
             (df['comingSoon'] == '+') | 
             (df['openingSoon'] == '+') | 
             (df['underConstruction'] == '+')).sum()
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael, the above gives me this error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1324, in __invert__
    new_data = self._mgr.apply(operator.invert)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 407, in apply
    applied = b.apply(f, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py", line 346, in apply
    result = func(self.values, **kwargs)
TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'str'`

Comment: and when I try without ~ then I get this error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'bool'

Comment: @Baobab1988 - It means `FALSE` are not boolean, but strings, so need `(df['True/False'] == 'FALSE')`

Comment: I've tried as you suggested, but now it throws this error: TypeError: Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [bool] array and scalar of type [bool]

Comment: @Baobab1988 - What is `print (df.dtypes)` before my solution?

Comment: it says 'object' for all columns in my dataframe. for example: `status object True/False object dtype: object`

Comment: @Baobab1988 - So try change `df['True/False'] == 'FALSE')` to `df['True/False'] == 'False')`